# Randomly remove 20 consecutive data values from a column of data which has c.180 values in total

Tags: r

I have a column of data whose order in the rows they appear are important, which signify an order of occurrence. What I would like to do is randomly remove 20 consecutive values in that df$col.

I know how to randomly remove 20 data values from a column:

```
flow.df %>% sample_frac(0.8)
```

But don't have any idea how to do randomly remove 20 consecutive values.

Amy help is much appreciated with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[-c(seq(sample(nrow(df) - 19, 1), length.out = 20)), ]
```

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks for this code it has been a real help. Is there a way of randomly 'removing' the 20 consecutive data points in the df , but have them replaced by NA, maintaining the order of values in the df?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I totally missunderstood your question. You can try the following:

```
i = sample(1:(nrow(df)-19),1)
df[-(i:(i+19)),]
```

Here you take just one index and then remove it and the following 20. I removed the possibility of selecting an index >160 as you won't be able to take the following 20. You can adjust this depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat verbose function that can probably be written shorter and faster:

```
remove_random_n <- function(df, n = 20) {
  rows <- nrow(df)
  upper_bound <- rows - n
  removal_start <- floor(runif(1, 1, upper_bound))
  removal_indices <- seq(removal_start, removal_start + n - 1)
  df[-removal_indices, ]
}
```